# Laravel auth session initiated from a different domain doesn't persist

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

Is there anyone familiar with s built with  running on one domain (laravelapi.com) and  apps connecting to it from another domain (angularapp.com)?

How did you handle the authentication session?

Imagine there is a route in the API like `/auth/get-user`, which does this:

```
AuthController extends Controller
{
    //Accessed through /auth/get-user
    public function getUser()
    {
        return Response::json(Auth::user());
    }
}
```

As long as the app and the API are in the same domain, the above code works fine, but when I move them to separate domains, the API just returns a 401 Unauthorized error.

I have set the above error to be returned when `! Auth::check ()`.

So simply, Laravel's auth session doesn't persist when requested through another domain. How would you face this issue?

Comment: You would need to set the cookie domain in `app/config/cookie.php` to the domain you want session persistence in.

Comment: @DavidBarker: Thanks for the comment Dav. But what if I am building a public API?

Comment: @DavidBarker: Besides, I did test it with setting the cookie domain to my testing app's domain, it didn't work either.

Comment: Then session cookies probably aren't the answer. You want to look into a more robust authentication system such as oAuth2 for public API's.

Comment: @DavidBarker: It might be insecure, but this is a test. I want to first build it this way -- then I'll evaluate it's ups and downs and choose a better one.

As it is already possible to authenticate with session variables within the same domain -- and not from a different domain even when I set the cookie domain -- I believe there should be something simple I am missing. I'd like to get that sorted out before I decide on using a better method.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't highlighting the security implications. I was highlighting the fact you will need abstract session handling. Cookies won't do that... look at oAuth2.